# Link object files from header files in real mode when using GCC -m16 option?

Tags: gcc, x86, header-files, x86-16, osdev

I would like to implement header files in my c-code which consists partly of *GCC* inline assembly code for 16 bit real mode but i seem to have linking problems. This is what my header file `console.h` looks like:

```
#ifndef CONSOLE_H
#define CONSOLE_H

extern void kprintf(char*);

#endif
```

and this is `console.c`:

```
#include "console.h"


void kprintf(char *string)
{
    for(int i=0;string[i]!='\0';i++)
    {
        asm("mov $0x0e,%%ah;"
            "mov $0x00,%%bh;"
            "mov %0,%%al;"
            "int $0x10"::"g"(string[i]):"eax", "ebx");
    }
}
```

the last one `hellworld.c`:

```
asm("jmp main");
#include "console.h"

void main()
{   
    asm("mov $0x1000,%ax;"
        "mov %ax,%es;"
        "mov %ax,%ds");
    char string[]="hello world";
    kprintf(string);

    asm(".rept 512;"
        "hlt;"
        ".endr");
}
```

My bootloader is in `bootloader.asm`:

```
org 0x7c00
bits    16

section .text
mov ax,0x1000
mov ss,ax
mov sp,0x000
mov esp,0xfffe
xor ax,ax
mov es,ax 
mov ds,ax

mov [bootdrive],dl

mov bh,0
mov bp,zeichen    
mov ah,13h
mov bl,06h
mov al,1
mov cx,6
mov dh,010h
mov dl,01h
int 10h

load:
mov dl,[bootdrive]
xor ah,ah
int 13h
jc load

load2:
mov ax,0x1000
mov es,ax
xor bx,bx

mov ah,2
mov al,1
mov cx,2
xor dh,dh

mov dl,[bootdrive]
int 13h
jc load2

mov ax,0
mov es,ax
mov bh,0
mov bp,zeichen3

mov ah,13h
mov bl,06h
mov al,1
mov cx,13
mov dh,010h
mov dl,01h
int 10h

mov ax,0x1000
mov es,ax
mov ds,ax
jmp 0x1000:0x000

zeichen db  'hello2'
zeichen3 db 'soweit so gut'
bootdrive db 0
times   510 - ($-$$)    hlt
dw  0xaa55
```

Now I use the following buildscript `build.sh`:

```
#!bin/sh

nasm -f bin bootloader.asm -o bootloader.bin
gcc hellworld.c -m16 -c -o hellworld.o -nostdlib -ffreestanding
gcc console.c -m16 -c -o console.o -nostdlib link.ld -ffreestanding
ld  -melf_i386 -Ttext=0x0000 console.o hellworld.o -o hellworld.elf
objcopy -O binary hellworld.elf hellworld.bin
cat bootloader.bin hellworld.bin >disk.img
qemu-system-i386 disk.img
```

and the linkscript `link.ld`:

```
/*
*  link.ld
*/
OUTPUT_FORMAT(elf32-i386)
SECTIONS
{
   . = 0x0000;
   .text : { *(.startup); *(.text) }
   .data : { *(.data) }
   .bss  : { *(.bss)  }
}
```

Unfortunately it isn't working because it doesn't print the expected `hello world`. I think there must be something wrong with the linking command:

```
ld -melf_i386 -Ttext=0x0000 console.o hellword.o link.ld -o hellworld.elf`
```

How do I link header-files in 16-bit mode correctly?

When I write the `kprintf` function directly in the `hellworld.c` it is working correctly. I am using `Linux Mint Cinnamon Version 18 64 bit` for development.

Comment: Do the bootloader work? And doesn't qemu allow you to attach a debugger so you can step through the code?

Comment: the bootloader works because as i said it prints out` "hello world" ` when i give the function definition inside `hellworld.c`

Comment: would you be so kind and tell me what the commands are for the debugging

Comment: How do you know your `asm("jmp main");` code is generated at the correct place if you have several .o files ? What if your console.o code gets added  in front of it.  Perhaps your linker script needs a `STARTUP(hellworld.o) directive.

Comment: if i switch their place or leave out `asm("jmp main")` it doesnt matter the problem still remains

Comment: how do i write the `startup` command

Comment: "link header files" that isn't a thing. Header files are not linked. Their text is incorporated into the source they are `#include`d from.

Comment: i link object files but it is still a problem with a header file

Comment: @albert the problem is nothing to do with the header file. What you really mean, and what you should say, is that the issue arises when you call a function defined in a separate compilation unit (source file). You could have the same problem without having a header file at all.

Comment: i should i rewrite my title then?

Comment: @Some programmer dude i am able to disassemble with `objdump -MI8086 -mi386 -bbinary -D disk.bin` when i create a `bin` file before hand

Comment: @albert yes, of course you should rewrite your title and the relevant parts of your question.

Comment: I don't know definitively, but I wonder if `OUTPUT_FORMAT(elf32-i386)` is appropriate for 16-bit...

Comment: the question is solved it didnt boot enough space

Comment: @twalberg : For 16-bit code elf32-i386 is perfectly fine since it will eventually be converted to flat binary with _OBJCOPY_ .

Comment: cool thats very nice of you thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The header files are not really the issue at all. When you restructured the code and split it into multiple objects it has identified issues with how you build and how `jmp main` is placed into the final kernel file.

I have created a [set of files](http://www.capp-sysware.com/misc/stackoverflow/41244144/) that make all the adjustments discussed below  if you wish to test the complete set of changes to see if they rectify your problems.

---

Although you show the linker script, you aren't actually using it. In your build file you have:

```
ld  -melf_i386 -Ttext=0x0000 console.o hellworld.o -o hellworld.elf
```

It should be:

```
ld  -melf_i386 -Tlink.ld console.o hellworld.o -o hellworld.elf
```

When using `-c` (compiles but doesn't link) with *GCC* don't specify `link.ld` as a linker script. The linker script can be specified at link time when you invoke *LD*. This line:

```
gcc console.c -m16 -c -o console.o -nostdlib link.ld -ffreestanding
```

Should be:

```
gcc console.c -m16 -c -o console.o -nostdlib -ffreestanding
```

In order for this linker script to locate the `jmp main` in a place that is **first** in the output kernel file you need to change:

```
asm("jmp main");
```

To:

```
asm(".pushsection .startup\r\n"
    "jmp main\r\n"
    ".popsection\r\n");
```

The `.pushsection` temporarily changes the section to `.startup`, outputs the instruction `jmp main` and then restores the section with `.popsection` to whatever it was before. The linker script deliberately places anything in the `.startup` section before anything else. This ensures the `jmp main` (or any other instructions you place there) appear as the very first instructions of the output kernel file. The `\r\n` can be replaced by `;` (semicolon). `\r\n` makes for prettier output if you ever have *GCC* generate an assembly file.

---

As mentioned in the comments of a now deleted question your kernel file exceeds the size of a single sector. When you don't have a linker script, the default one will place the data section after the code. Your code has repeated the `hlt` instruction so that your kernel is greater than 1 sector (512 bytes) and your bootloader only reads a single sector with [*Int 13h/AH=2h*](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0607.htm) .

To rectify this remove:

```
asm(".rept 512;"
    "hlt;"
    ".endr");
```

And replace it with:

```
asm("cli;"
    "hlt;");
```

You should be mindful that as your kernel grows you'll need to adjust the number of sectors read in `bootloader.asm` to ensure all of the kernel is loaded into memory.

I also suggest that to keep *QEMU*, and other virtual machines happy that you simply generate a well known disk image size and place the bootloader and kernel inside it. Rather than:

```
cat bootloader.bin hellworld.bin >disk.img
```

Use this:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=disk.img bs=1024 count=1440
dd if=bootloader.bin of=disk.img seek=0 conv=notrunc
dd if=hellworld.bin of=disk.img seek=1 conv=notrunc
```

The first command makes a zero filled file of 1440kb. This is the exact size of a 1.44MB floppy. The second command inserts `bootloader.bin` in the first sector without truncating the disk file. The third command places the kernel file into the disk images starting at the second sector on the disk without truncating the disk image.

---

I had made available a slightly improved [linker script](http://www.capp-sysware.com/misc/stackoverflow/41234695/link.ld). It was amended to remove some of the potential cruft that the linker may insert into the kernel that won't be of much use and specifically identifies some of the sections like `.rodata` (read only data) etc.

```
/*
*  link.ld
*/
OUTPUT_FORMAT(elf32-i386)
SECTIONS
{
   . = 0x0000;
   .text : { *(.startup); *(.text) }
   .data : { *(.data); *(.rodata) }
   .bss  : { *(COMMON); *(.bss) }

    /DISCARD/ : {
        *(.eh_frame);
        *(.comment);
        *(.note.gnu.build-id);
    }
}
```

---

### Other Comments

Not related to your question but this code can be removed:

```
asm("mov $0x1000,%ax;"
    "mov %ax,%es;"
    "mov %ax,%ds");
```

You do this in [bootloader.asm](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41234695/3857942), so setting these segment registers again with the same value won't do anything useful.

---

You can improve the [extended assembly template](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html) by using [input constraints](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Constraints.html#Constraints) to pass the values you need via register *EAX*(*AX*) and *EBX*(*BX*) rather than coding the moves inside the template. Your code could have looked like:

```
void kprintf(const char *string)
{
    while (*string)
    {
        asm("int $0x10"
        :
        :"a"((0x0e<<8) | *string++), /* AH = 0x0e, AL = char to print */
         "b"(0));                    /* BH = 0x00 page #
                                        BL = 0x00 unused in text mode */
    }
}
```

`<<` is the *C* [bit shift left operator](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_operators.htm). `0x0e<<8` would shift `0x0e` left 8 bits which would be `0x0e00`. `|` is bitwise *OR* which effectively places the character to print in the lower 8 bits. That value is then passed into the *EAX* register by the assembly template via [input constraint](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Machine-Constraints.html#Machine-Constraints) `"a"`.

Comment: What does << mean?

Comment: That thing with the link script was a miscopy again sry

Comment: Great explanation!

Comment: the interrupt handler has to be written for BIOS mode, right?

Comment: @albert : I'm unsure what you are asking. BIOS interrupts are only available in 16-bit real mode. If you change to 32-bit protected mode they will no longer function and will likely reset the machine. In protected mode you have to basically talk to devices through memory mapped IO, data ports etc.

Comment: when i use inline assembler how to i change to protected mode because i cant just right `bits 32` so i have to compile it with `-m32` and than `ld -melf_i386...` and `cat` it with the `-m16` compiled files right?

Comment: Easiest place to change to protected mode is in bootloader.asm and write it in assembly. You have to create a GDT, load it, change into protected mode, and use a _JMP_ to set the _CS_ descriptor to put you properly into 32-bit mode. I have given you links to tutorial using _NASM_ to switch to protected mode.

Comment: ive read this tutorial but how does it work with inline assembler

Comment: @albert It is far more complex with inline assembler. You will pull your hair out unless you simply do it with the other startup code you have written in bootloader.asm

Comment: so it wouldn't work the way i suggested with inline assembler?

Comment: but the problem is i have to increase the bootloader for this so its better to write another assembly file *.asm isnt it?

Comment: It is possible but way too complex and problematic. Take my advice, you have already had to write assembly code to properly set things up in bootloader.asm, I recommend you switch to protected mode there. If you switch to protected mode there then you can simply compile all the _C_ code with `-m32` rather than `-m16` and you'll have to remove all the BIOS calls from inline assembly inside the _C_ code (as they won't work in protected mode)

Comment: @albert There is more than adequate space in the first 512 bytes to do everything you have already done, plus add a GDT and switch to protected mode and then transfer control to you _C_ kernel.

Comment: but i basically have to jump from my `main.c` back to my `bootloader.asm` when i setup my `GDT` in `main.c`

Comment: @albert No, the easiest way is to setup the GDT, enter protected mode then transfer control to the 32-bit _C_ code. Once transferred to your _C_ code you are in protected mode and you don't have to do any of that setup again (no need to call anything in bootloader.asm after you are in the _C_ code)

Comment: or i jump to 32 bit before and do the `GDT` in 32 bit mode

Comment: @albert : As I have been saying easiest way is to get into protected mode in bootloader.asm and jump to your 32-bit _C_ code. All the 32-bit setup is done prior to the _C_ code being executed. Once in the _C_ code everything is set the way it needs to be.

Comment: but i can't get into protected mode without setting up the `GDT`, right?

Comment: @albert Correct, you need a GDT to get into protected mode, and you can create the GDT and load it with assembler code in bootloader.asm. The entire GDT is placed into bootloader.asm, the code to load it, to set up the segment selectors and the final jump to the _C_ code is all written in assembly (_NASM_)

Comment: do you know how to see the symbol code when debugging nasm files that have `org...` in it

Comment: @albert Not sure what you are looking for. NASM supports a limited assembler list option `-l bootloader.lst` on _NASM_ command line would generate a list file but it isn't very good. But you can comment out (remove) the the `ORG 0x7c00` and assemble link with `nasm -g -f elf32 -o bootloader.o bootloader.asm`, then
`ld -Ttext=0x7c00 -melf_i386 -o bootloader.elf bootloader.o`, then 
`objcopy -O binary bootloader.elf bootloader.bin`, then
`objdump -St -Mi8086 bootloader.elf >bootloader.lst` . When finished `bootloader.elf` should contain symbolic debug info.

Comment: @albert And `bootloader.lst` would contain a nice text file with debug symbols and source code in it, and `bootloader.bin` would be your regular bin file that can be placed in the boot sector

Comment: @Michael Petch Since you have such a vast knowledge about OSdev could you please have a look at my question: Constant reboot after setting up the GDI and protected mode

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to say without knowing what your `bootloader.asm` does, but:

1. The link order must be wrong;

   `ld  -melf_i386 -Ttext=0x0000 console.o hellworld.o -o hellworld.elf`

   should be:

   `ld  -melf_i386 -Ttext=0x0000 hellworld.o console.o -o hellworld.elf`

   (Edit: I see that you have a linker script which would remove the need for this re-arrangement, but you're not using it for the link).
2. I suspect that your bootloader loads a single sector, and your padding:

   ```
   asm(".rept 512;"
       "hlt;"
       ".endr");
   ```

   ... prevents the code from the other object file from ever being loaded, since it pads `hellword.o` to (more than) the size of a sector.

The problem is nothing to do with the use of header files, it is because you have two compilation units which become separate objects, and the combined size of both when linked is larger than a sector (512 bytes).

Comment: yeah its the second thing thanks i repaced it with `cli; halt`

Comment: @albert I'm quite confident that the first point must also be addressed. The bootloader must be assuming an entry point at the beginning of the sector and the only way to ensure that is to swap the order of the objects when linking.